# Installing packages with PIP on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, pip

I've been searching and searching and cannot find where pip installs packages on windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just found it. Literally, right after I posted this question. For anyone else who is looking, it is at C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages.

Thanks!